# Thinking sphinx sorting on multiple fields

Tags: sorting, thinking-sphinx

I am searching for the model Projects. Projects belongs_to Companies, so all Projects in the list can have the same Company attached to it. An example of a result list:

```
CompanyA - ProjectA
CompanyA - ProjectO
CompanyA - ProjectC
CompanyA - ProjectB
CompanyB - ProjectU
CompanyB - ProjectI
```

I can sort on Project name, but then the Company name column can be random like above. I would like to sort this column as secondary field. Can this be done? I have read that Sphinx is converting the fields sorting to an id, probably to save memory, but this can't possibly limit the sorting in this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use SPH_SORT_EXTENDED mode for this:

```
$sph->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "Project ASC, Company ASC");
```

([sort mode docs](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.1/sorting-modes.html))

**Edit:** above example is PHP but [it appears that](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#sorting) Thinking Sphinx exposes the feature similarly:

```
Article.search "term", :sort_mode => :extended,
  :order => "Project ASC, Company ASC"
```